# How to open popup after specific time

Tags: javascript

I am sorry, but I really not found the answer regarding my question that How to open a popup window after specific time ? I need to embed this in my webpage where a popup will appear after 10 second to greet the user. please help me to solve this, actually I am not a JavaScript guy

Comment: what should that popoup window contains ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cmLRr/

Answer (score 5):

Since your question does not specify what attempts you've made I'm giving you guidelines rather than code. Feel free to ask questions about them

- Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) to execute code after a certain amount of time.
- Use [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert) to create a popup.

Note - some people consider `alert` base user experience - one way around this is using a [modal-dialog](/questions/tagged/modal-dialog)